# Little Endian Encoding

Tags: encoding, endianness

The following byte sequence is encoded as Little Endian Unsigned Int.

```
F0 00 00 00
```

I just read about endianness. Just wanted to verify if it is 240 decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating the byte sequence to bits...

[1111 0000] [0000 0000] [0000 0000] [0000 0000]

Converting the first byte to decimal...

= 0*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^6 + 1*2^7

Doing the math...

= 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 = 240

Comment: How did you transfer that to bits?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 0x000000F0 = 240.

If it were big-endian, it would be 0xF0000000 = 4026531840 (or -268435456 if signed).